# How to mock the class object which is created inside a method using new keyword in MOQ

Tags: c#, moq, rhino-mocks, testcase

I am using Moq to write a unit test cases.

Code:

```
public class SavingAccount  
{  
    public void Data()  
    {  
        //Some logic
    }  
}  

public class Account  
{  
    public void GetAccountDetails()  
    {  
        SavingAccount savingAccount = new SavingAccount();  
        savingAccount.Data();  

        //Some logic
    }  
}
```

Test case:

```
[TestClass]
public class AccountTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetAccountDetails()
    {
       using(var mock = new AutoMock.GetLoose())
       {
          var mockAccount = mock.Create<Account>();
          mockAccount.GetAccountDetails();
       }
    }
}
```

Here I need to mock the `savingAccount.Data();` method of `SavingAccount` class.
But when I run the above test, `savingAccount` object actually calling the `Data()` method. I don't want to call it, jut want to mock it.

Also I don't to change the above code. I don't want to use the interface.

Comment: Are you using dependency injection? You could change the original to use an injected factory method.

Comment: No John. I am not using DI.

Comment: You'll have to go look for a mocking framework that can mock class initialization. Moq however does not have that feature and I know of no free framework that can.

Comment: The currently shown code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns which make it difficult to test the subject code in isolation. That should be seen as a code smell and refactored accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

**Method 1.** Create a factory and pass it to `Account` when you instantiate it. When you need a SavingAccount, call the factory:

```
    public class Account
    {
        private readonly IAccountFactory _accountFactory;

        public Account(IAccountFactory accountFactory)
        {
            _accountFactory = accountFactory;
        }

        public void GetAccountDetails()  
        {  
            SavingAccount savingAccount = _accountFactory.CreateSavingAccount();
            savingAccount.Data();  

            //Some logic
        }   
    }
```

Then you can pass an mocked implementation of `IAccountFactory` into `Account`. This is the way I recommend doing it, and will make a transition to dependency injection in the future easier if you ever decide to do that.

**Method 2.** Move instantiation of SavingAccount into a mockable method:

```
    public class Account  
    {  
        public void GetAccountDetails()  
        {  
            SavingAccount savingAccount = CreateSavingAccount();
            savingAccount.Data();  

            //Some logic
        }

        protected virtual SavingAccount CreateSavingAccount()
        {
            return new SavingAccount();
        }
    }
```

Now you can mock `CreateSavingAccount` and have it return a mocked instance of `SavingAccount`. Note that you will also need to change `public void Data()` to `public virtual void Data()` so that you can mock it.

Comment: Thank you John. I don't want to change my code at all. For you solution, I need to change my code. Do you have any other way.

Comment: There is no other way that doesn't involve modifying your code.

Comment: ok. If I follow the method 2, then how will my test case will look. Can you provide test case example for method 2.

Comment: @John is the effort needed to get that second workaround to work worth it? Their code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns. While introducing the factory method would allow for overriding the creation of the `SavingAccount` you would then need to either refactor that class to allow the members to be mockable by a mocking framework or manually create a derived class and new over the said method to avoid calling the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit old question but nevertheless. There are modern mocking frameworks that can mock the new operator and the creation of new objects such as JustMock. Here is an example of how you can mock the `SavingAccount` class.

```
// Arrange the what SavingAccount should do 
var savingAccount = new SavingAccount();
Mock.Arrange(() => savingAccount.Data()).DoNothing();

// Arrange that every new creation of SavingAccount will return the object you've created above
Mock.Arrange(() => new SavingAccount()).Returns(savingAccount);
```